# Displaying multiple types of views in UITableView using subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have some static `UIWebView` content that I am trying to load into `UITableView` cells, along with some labels in alternating cells. Here is what I am trying (which is not working):
In viewDidLoad:

```
commentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
```

In viewWillAppear:

```
 [commentArray removeAllObjects];
 [commentArray addObject:@"sketch here"];
 [commentArray addObject:@"Heading1"];
 [commentsJComments loadHTMLString:htmlString1 baseURL:baseURL];
 [commentArray addObject:commentsJComments];
 [commentArray addObject:@"Heading2"];
 [commentsJComments loadHTMLString:htmlString2 baseURL:baseURL];
 [commentArray addObject:commentsJComments];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:

    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyTableViewCellSubclass *cell = (MyTableViewCellSubclass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCellSubclass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
     // This image below ends up in every cell of my TableView:
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Steve_Jobs.jpeg"];
    else {

        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1)

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        else {
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
            NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

            [cell.textWV loadHTMLString:[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] baseURL:baseURL];
        }
    }
```

My subclassed TableViewCell:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.textWV = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 0, 300, 400)];
    self.textWV.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.textWV.delegate = self;
    self.descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];
    self.descriptionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f];
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 281, 400)];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Steve_Jobs.jpeg"];
    [self addSubview:self.textWV];
    [self addSubview:self.descriptionLabel];
    [self addSubview:self.imageView];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: And what are you getting now?

Comment: I get 5 cells loaded with the UIImageView, containing the "Steve_Jobs.jpeg".

Comment: NSLog your commentArray and check whether the data are there.

Comment: I did that.  It has what I want/expect it to have.

Comment: Then I think, the imageView is covering the text contents. Please check the frames of your control.

Comment: Sorry, I get 2 cells loaded with the "Steve_Jobs.jpeg" UIImageView.

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean by the frames of my "control".

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Array Properlly,and then try,i thing your app is crashing,and error is related array.

Comment: No, it's not crashing.  It runs fine.  I just don't get the display I want.  It always displays the contents of the first index in my commentsArray in the proper format, which is as a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line `self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Steve_Jobs.jpeg"];` from your subclassed tableview cell and recheck the frame of the label and webview.

Comment: That causes a big improvement: now the first and second cells display correctly.  The third cell, which is a UIWebView, displays partially and only when it is about to scroll off the screen… weird.  The 4th and 5th cells are now blank.

Comment: what is the height of cell you are returning?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the third cell.  It looks to be about 300 pixels high.  Along with the content, the border with the next cell only appears when the content is about to go off the screen.

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   
    int xxx;
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        xxx = 400;
    else {
        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
            xxx = 300;
        else xxx = 30;
    }
    
    return xxx;

Comment: Hope your tableView height was not limited. One thing you can do for finding the problem is to give background color to ur tableview and cells. Try giving different bgColor for different cells, so you will get an idea on how much area one takes or any overlapping etc..